# Passing an id to create review

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Im attempting to pass user_id and a game_id to create a review.  I can get it to work if I just select the game_id in a dropdown, but unable to pass the game_id correctly...

here is my code for the form

```
<div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, id: :review_user_id, class:"form-control", value: current_user.id, type: :hidden %>
  </div>

<div class="field form-group">
    <%= form.number_field :game_id, id: :review_game_id, class:"form-control", value: @game_id, type: :hidden %>
  </div>
```

My Reviews Controller

```
ReviewsController

....

def new
    @review = current_user.reviews.build
  end
def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
   def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:reviewed_game, :rating, :game_id, :user_id)
```

Pretty sure it has to do with something in my Controller, im not passing something correctly.  I attempted to do something like this with my GameController:

```
def create
 @game = Game.new(params[:review])
...
end
```

no luck, Im pretty green to RoR...any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to pass the user id in the first place since its stored in the session (or in a token if you're using token based auth). In fact doing so makes it trivial to spoof it for a malicous user.

Comment: Im using Devise gem for my auth, I tried taking out the user_id but the review wouldnt post.  If I keep the user_id in there It will be created, but I can get the review on a specific game_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Rails!

Looks to me like you're not setting `@game_id` anywhere, so that value will be nil, and thus an empty value tag in your HTML. So when the form is submitted, no `:game_id` will be in your params.

What you're trying to build sounds like a great case for [nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

In your `config/routes.rb` you would have something like

```
resources :games do
  resources :reviews
end
```

So when you visit a URL like "/games/123/reviews/new", you'll hit the `ReviewsController` but there'll be a `params[:game_id]` equal to `123`.

Your `ReviewsController` would look something like this

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    @review = current_user.reviews.new
  end

  def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params)
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    @review.game = @game

    if @review.save
    # etc.
  end
end
```

Your reviews/new view template would have a form that points to this nested URL.

I believe you can do that with [form_with](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object)

So, something like:

```
form_with model: [@game, @review] do |f|
  # form code
```

When you run `current_user.reviews.new`, the Review instance will automatically have the `:user_id` attribute assigned. So you don't need to have the `user_id` floating around in your params, which as [max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) points out, is a security flaw.

Similarly, `@review.game = @game` should assign the correct `game_id`.

By taking this approach, the only real information you need from the user is the rating, your routes will handle the `Game` in question, and Devise's `current_user` will handle the `User`.

I hope this helps in some way. Persistence is fruitful.

Comment: thank you for this! its def set me on the right path to fixing my issue.  I am able to create reviews now, and took out the user_id.  Im atttempting to use a collection_select    ```<%= form.label :game_id %>
   <%= collection_select(@game, :game_id, Game.all, :id, :name) %>``` so that way the user selects the game from the list, but unable to get the correct game, it will only work if im in the path games/1/reviews/new.  Is there a way to make this work so when they click on the dropdown and select the game it writes a review for that game? thanks again

Comment: I think you should be able to use `form_with model: @review` and the have a a simple select_tag like `select_tag "game_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Game.all, "id", "name")`. This should work because the `params` object should now have a `game_id` value. (Providing your `create` action still looks for `Game.find(params[:game_id])`).

To be clear, your Game select should NOT start `form.some_tag` because you don't want its value nested in `params[:review]`.